# How to pass ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>from one activity to another

Tags: android

How i can pass Array List from one Activity to another my array list is shown as follows

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Use [`putExtra(String, Serializable)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.io.Serializable%29) to pass the value in an Intent and [`getSerializableExtra(String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getSerializableExtra(java.lang.String)) method to retrieve the data.

**Passing an `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` from Activity A to Activity B**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, B.class);
HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();
hm.put("sunil", "sahoo");
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
arl.add(hm);
intent.putExtra("arraylist", arl);
startActivityForResult(intent, 500);
```

**Retrieve the data in Activity B**

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arraylist");
System.out.println("...serialized data.."+arl);
```

Comment: getSerializableExtra doesn't seem to exist, im using Honeycomb.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Bundle to pass elements from one Activity to another.

Check this out: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html

You create the Bundle, put it into the Intent, and then on the new activity, you get it and extract the elements you need.

It goes like this:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
String s = "hello";
b.putString("example", s);
intent.putExtras(b);
```

and then on the new activity:

```
Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras(); 
String s = b.getString("example");
```

Comment: rather he can use intent.putStringArrayList("name",value),, but he has Hashmap objects stored in it.. not String...

Answer (score 1):

here is another technique,
I used following line to define ArrayList in firstClass.

```
static ArrayList al=new ArrayList();
```

In second activity, i used following line to get the data of ArrayList from firstClass,

```
firstClass.al.size();
```

Comment: He can certainly do that, but usually it is not a good idea to make something static just because you need it somewhere else.

Comment: If static is not a good idea, then why java programing language contains "static" keyword.

Answer (score 0):

my idea, you can define a global static variable for this data set on the package and save it first before jump to another activity.