# How to transfer an ArrayList of objects from one Activity to another

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an ArrayList of objects in one activity and I need this arrayList in another activity.

Is there a solution to transger this ArrayList? I know i can use intents for ArrayList of Strings but what's about the ArrayList of objects?

Thank you.

Comment: I think this answers your question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355787/how-to-pass-arraylist-from-one-activity-to-another

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complex types  passed by means of `Parcelable` or do the `serialization` to another kind of primitive object that you can put to Intent's extras. see this question:

[Help with passing ArrayList and parcelable Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819238/help-with-passing-arraylist-and-parcelable-activity)

and this tutorial:

[Passing a list of objects between Activities](http://androidideasblog.blogspot.in/2010/02/passing-list-of-objects-between.html)

Comment: Hi @imrankhan, I am trying to use the tutorial for parce an arrayList of objects but i have a roblem with the line b.putParcelableArrayList("categories", categories); when I am trying to parce. It says: The method putParcelableArrayList(String, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable>) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, ArrayList<Article>)

Comment: Ana,in example Category class contain an String category; and an ArrayList of Class Item.class

Comment: @Ana : if you have any problem in implementing example from tutorial then download code from here [Passobjectlist](http://www.4shared.com/rar/8KPdYtYO/Passobjectlist.html
). i have created for you.thanks -:)