# Insterting ArrayList on Bundle

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, bundle

I have an ArrayList of the following type:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data
```

I am attempting to pass on this `data` to a `Bundle` I did not find any method to implement this. The closest I came to this was :

```
putParcelableArrayList
```

can someone help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>from one activity to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355787/how-to-pass-arraylisthashmapstring-stringfrom-one-activity-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to pass data b/w activities. You can do something like this

Sender

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arl = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
intent.putExtra("orderlist", arl);
```

Reciever

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) intent.getSerializableExtra("orderList");
```