# Parse Json Object in android?

Tags: java, android, json

I am developing one application in that i have to receive data from server ,I am successfully read data . here i have problem i receive data from server code wrote in AsyncTask,and send data from AsyncTask to My activity,here i send only one data out of three,my json object have 3 objects.i can get 3 objects in AsyncTask but not getting in Activity

my AsyncTask

```
 public class ReceivingLatLongAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

Context mContext;

JSONArray jsonArryDetails=null;

public static final String DETAILS = "locations";
public static final String LAT = "lat";
public static final String LNG = "lng";
public static final String ADDRESS = "address";
public static final String CTIME = "ctime";

private String lat1;
private String lng1;
private String address1;
private String time1;


public ReceivingLatLongAsync(Context context){

    this.mContext = context;

}
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(mContext);
     pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
     pDialog.setCancelable(false);
     pDialog.show();

}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ServiceHandler serviceHandler= new ServiceHandler();

    String jSonString = `serviceHandler.makeServiceCall
         (TrafficConstants.RECIEVE_LATLON_POL_URL, ServiceHandler.POST);`

    Log.e("Response: ", "> " + jSonString);

    if(jSonString != null){

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jSonString);

            jsonArryDetails = jsonObject.getJSONArray(DETAILS);

            for(int i = 0;i<jsonArryDetails.length();i++){

                JSONObject mapDetails =        
                          jsonArryDetails.getJSONObject(0);

                lat1 = mapDetails.getString(LAT);
                lng1 = mapDetails.getString(LNG);
                address1 = mapDetails.getString(ADDRESS);
                time1 = mapDetails.getString(CTIME);


                Log.e("ADDRESS1", address1);
                Log.e("TIME2",time1);



            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    pDialog.dismiss();

    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,GetLatLongForTPActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("LAT", lat1);
    intent.putExtra("LNG", lng1);
    intent.putExtra("ADDRESS", address1);
    intent.putExtra("time",time1);

    mContext.startActivity(intent);
}

    }
```

my activty

```
  public class GetLatLongForTPActivity extends FragmentActivity 
                                implements LocationListener{

  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_lat_long_for_tp);

    timeEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.timeId);
    submitBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.subId);   

     Intent intent = getIntent();
     String anotherLAT=intent.getStringExtra("LAT");
     String anotherLNG=intent.getStringExtra("LNG");

     Log.e(" NEW LATLONG",anotherLAT);

  }
```

Comment: try  _startActivity(intent);_ not  _mContext.startActivity(intent);_

Comment: you must send one Array of object, create one class with those object and send that array, for sending your array you must implement `parcelable`

Comment: for parsing option, try Gson: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21480634/unable-to-loop-through-dynamic-json-string-recursively-in-android/21480997#21480997

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
 JSONObject mapDetails =        
                      jsonArryDetails.getJSONObject(0);
```

to

```
 JSONObject mapDetails =        
                      jsonArryDetails.getJSONObject(i);
```

You have to add something like

```
   ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

   for(int i = 0;i<jsonArryDetails.length();i++){
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject mapDetails =        
                      jsonArryDetails.getJSONObject(i);

            lat1 = mapDetails.getString(LAT);
            lng1 = mapDetails.getString(LNG);
            address1 = mapDetails.getString(ADDRESS);
            time1 = mapDetails.getString(CTIME);
            map.put(LAT, lat1);
            map.put(LNG, lg1);
            map.put(ADDRESS, address1 );
            map.put(CTIME, time1 );

            mylist.add(map);

        }
```

Comment: i have to send all objects to activity is it possible?

Comment: @Durga after do this you need see [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355787/how-to-pass-arraylisthashmapstring-stringfrom-one-activity-to-another) for sending your list to activity

Comment: thank you how to send this array list to my activity,how to read in that

Comment: no ,with this all lat long values i want to show locations on map

Answer (score 3):

Becouse it is an jsonArray and now you send only the last object not the entier array

Comment: yes the best is to make get/set function and set the array on fist activity and take it with get in second activity

Comment: and with that you resolve the "send data via intent" problem that is not directly indicated.

Answer (score 0):

In for loop change the index :

```
        for(int i = 0;i<jsonArryDetails.length();i++){

            JSONObject mapDetails =jsonArryDetails.getJSONObject(i);
            //etc                                                ^ //change here
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class that stores the four fields you are using (lat,long,address,time), make that object parable, you could use this example: http://aryo.lecture.ub.ac.id/android-passing-arraylist-of-object-within-an-intent/ ;
And after that you can attach the array to the intent using:

```
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(String name, ArrayList<? extends Parcelable> value)
```

This would be the correct way to handle this, even if it's a little more complicated then you originally would have hoped.