# Android cannot pass List of string arrays to service class

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have this list of arrays that I need for my service to run

```
private List<String[]> commandList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Sample Data:

```
{"jump", "100", "100"}
{"walk", "100", "100"}
{"jump", "100", "100"}
```

I tried passing it through putExtra

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(macroService.class.getName());
serviceIntent.putExtra("CommandList", commandList);
context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

however the putExtra method only allows me to input strings and string arrays. Is there any way to pass a list of string arrays?

Comment: You have to use intent.putStringArrayListExtra("key",commandList); and get it with getStringArrayListExtra("key");

Comment: Or you can modify this answer by converting String[] to arrayList.....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355787/how-to-pass-arraylisthashmapstring-stringfrom-one-activity-to-another

Answer (score 2):

Use `putStringArrayListExtra` method instead of `putExtra`.

```
serviceIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("CommandList", commandList);
```

Also you can add your list in a `HashMap` and than pass this `HashMap` to next activity like below:

```
 HashMap<String, List> tmp = new HashMap<>();
 tmp.put("data", commandList);
 serviceIntent.putExtra("tmpData", tmp);
```

And to retrieve this data in the destination activity, you can do this:

```
 HashMap<String, List> tmp1 = (HashMap<String, List>) getIntent().getExtras().get("tmpData");
 List<String[]> testd = tmp1.get("data");
```

Comment: I tried this, but it only allows me to put List<String> not List<String[]>

Comment: Can show the sample data of `commandList`?

Comment: See the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see there is no function that does what you want, but, depending on how you are building and using the list, you could instead use a Bundle to collect your arrays and then add them to the intent with `putExtras(Bundle extras)`.